# What does this "... | ps `cat`" command do?

Tags: command-line, pipe, execute-command

On my Internet research, I found the following command as solution to find the process name of a window:

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID | sed 's/_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = //' | ps `cat`
```

I just do not understand what happens here after the first `|`.

Let's assume that `xprop _NET_WM_PID` outputs `1000` as process ID. What happens next? Why do we have a `cat` after `ps`? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`xprop ... | sed ...` is executed first, then `cat` reads its output. Due to the use of backticks, the output of cat is substituted in `` ps `cat` `` such that the command becomes `ps 1000`.

An alternative command that leads to the same result is:

```
ps $(xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d= -f2)
```

This works as follows:

1. Execute `xprop _NET_WM_PID` to retrieve the process ID of a window. After clicking a window, it outputs something like:

   ```
   _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 12345
   ```
2. Split at the `=` and take the second field. `cut -d= -f2` takes the `_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 12345` string from standard input and writes `12345` to standard output.
3. Finally run the `ps` command with `$(...)` substituted for the output of `...`, the command that gets executed is `ps  12345`. (side note: `` `...` `` can also be used instead of `$(...)`, though [there are some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9405478/427545))

Comment: Interesting "complexion", this `| command 'cat'` (I can't embed backticks in the backtick in comments?) ... the usual way is : `| xargs command` (with additionnal parameters to xargs, for example to limit to 1 or n arguments, etc)